# install windows vm on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: windows-7

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my laptop. I need to know install windows vm on this platform. I have for googled for responses but did not get any related to my question.

Hence I am seeking help on this forum

Answer (score 4):

I use VirtualBox to run Win7 and other OS's.

My client only allows Windows and I just go to full screen mode in their office and they don't know any better.

At home I use the seamless mode to get back and fourth quickly

Comment: Good idea, idk why it didn't occurred to me before.

Answer (score 1):

**VMware Player:**

Pros = Better virtual graphics emulation than many virtual machine products, free

Cons = The update feature likes to ask if you want to upgrade to VMware Workstation

**How To Install VMware Player On Ubuntu Via Terminal:**

Step #1 = Download the .bundle file:

VMware Player 5.0.2-1031769 X86-64 (Linux):
"http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/player/5.0.2/1031769/linux/core/VMware-Player-5.0.2-1031769.x86_64.bundle.tar"

or

VMware Player 5.0.2-1031769 X86-32 (Linux):
"http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/player/5.0.2/1031769/linux/core/VMware-Player-5.0.2-1031769.i386.bundle.tar"

Step #2 = Extract the .bundle from the .tar file, you can do this by double clicking and then using archive manager to extract the .bundle

Step #3 = In Terminal type:
"sudo sh /directoryyousavedto/player.bundle"

Step #4 = Follow the prompts To Complete The Installation

Step #5 = Launch VMware Player from your applications menu, and click "Create New Virtual Machine".

Sources = candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=670.0

**Virtualbox:**

Pros = Free, easy to install, supports tons of operating systems as guest

Cons = poor graphics performance, just to get aero in windows you have to use an experimental/unstable driver.

**How To Install Virtualbox:**

Step #1 = Download the .deb file:

Virtualbox 4.2.16 X86-64: "download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~quantal_amd64.deb"

or

Virtualbox 4.2.16 X86-32: "download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~quantal_i386.deb"

Step #2 = Download the extension pack for usb 2.0 support in your vm:

"download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.16-86992.vbox-extpack"

Step #3 = Browse to the location you downloaded to and double click the .deb file and choose open with Ubuntu Software Center.

Step #4 = Run virtualbox and import the extension pack by going to "file/preferences/extension/add package"

**Quemu:**

Pros = Free, many other products use code or improvements from it

Cons = gui must be installed seperately

**How To Install Quemu:**

Step #1 = In terminal type: "sudo apt-get install qemu "

Step #2 = In terminal type: "sudo apt-get install qtemu"

Step #3 = To Launch type: "sudo qtemu"

Sources = candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=720.0